# How to add new store information to email templates Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, email-templates

I'm trying to change the `store_email` variable which can be used in all email templates to `general/store_information/email` (a new system field I created).

This variable loads `trans_email/ident_support/email` system config value by default from the function `addEmailVariables` in `Magento\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate`.

I tried creating an after plugin for this function like this:

```
<?php

namespace Cmcs\Email\Plugin;

use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class AbstractTemplate
{
    /**
     * Change store email variable
     */
    public function afterAddEmailVariables(
        \Magento\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate $subject,
        $result,
        $variables,
        $storeId
    )
    {
        $store = $subject->getStore($storeId);
        $result['store_email'] = $subject->getValue(
            'general/store_information/email',
            ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            $store
        );
        return $result;
    }

}
```

and this is in my `di.xml`:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="\Magento\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate">
        <plugin name="Cmcs_Email::addEmailVariables" type="Cmcs\Email\Plugin\AbstractTemplate" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

But the `store_email` variable doesn't get changed...

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using variables in the template like this not work?

```
{{config path="trans_email/ident_general/name"}}
```

For example

```
{{config path="general/store_information/email"}}
```

Comment: I already tried `{{config path="general/store_information/email"}}` but doesn't work on it's own. While `trans_email/ident_general/name` should work, since it's default M2, but doesn't help in this situation.

Comment: What if you edit this in vendor as an experiment https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/9544fb243d5848a497d4ea7b88e08609376ac39e/app/code/Magento/Variable/etc/di.xml as in check this https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/24425

Comment: Adding `general/store_information/email` to `di.xml` in Magento_Variable module allows me to add `{{config path="general/store_information/email"}}` to any email template. Do you know of a way to put config values inside of translatable texts, e.g. `{{trans 'Email us at: CUSTOM_VARIABLE'}}`? Similar to how Magento does it with `{{trans 'If you have questions about your order, you can email us at <a href="mailto:%store_email">%store_email</a>' store_email=$store_email|raw}}`

Comment: I think this is what you need https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/variables-custom.html

Comment: Yep I know about that already, but I wanted to make a module so that I could use Magento's default behaviour to get the desired result and use it when necessary on new shops.